# Replaced Windows 7, but where did my old files go?

Tags: installation, partitioning, windows-7, files, migration

Ok, let me start by saying that I know nothing about Linux and that I switched because I was sick and tired of windows.

So I had Windows 7 on my `C:` drive and I chose to replace it with Ubuntu 12.10.
The problem is there I was prepared to have all my data erased from `C:` Drive but now it seems I can find anything at all!

There is no partition. Theres nothing. Frankly I'm bummed!

Where is my music that I had in my `D:` drive earlier and the movies in my `X:` drive!

Help!

[Edit]
To All Linux/Ubuntu newbies,

Do not do the Following:

I had Windows 7 Installed on 'C:' and other drives that had my own files were 'D:' and 'X:'.
I downloaded the ubuntu 12.10 iso from the website[not related: which had a few broken files so I used bit torrent to fix it] and did a USB boot.
I chose the **replace windows 7 with ubuntu** option. I didnt get any option to select my partition or anything, the thing just rolled and mowed down on everything I had..

Follow Lucio's comment to figure out how to do it right. And always have a backup.

Comment: I guess you don't have a backup? Did you use the option 'erase disk and install ubuntu'?

Comment: @ShaunakKar If you think that my answer has responded to your issue, you can [mark it as accepted](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/1141/62483) so this question remains as *answered*.

Answer (score 2):

*To see all your partitions (size, system, etc.) enter* `sudo fdisk -l` *in terminal.*

If you don't see your `D:` and/or `X:` partitions there, then is not much I can do.

If you selected the **Erase disk and install Ubuntu** option, then all the OS, partitions and files there (`C:` & `D:` & `X:`) are gone.

If you selected the **Something else** option, then depends of what you did there. Like if installed Ubuntu in the `C:` partition, then maybe your `D:` & `X:` partitions could  be fine.

---

What I can say is that you have to be very careful when you are preparing your HDD to install a new OS. You have to review twice all the options and actions that you take in the process. Read [this article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace) about disk space the is very useful for dual systems. And **always remember to create a backup with all your important information!**

Comment: Oh, sorry to heart that. Please, tell us what you did (editing your question). It could be useful for future users :)

Comment: There is some partition recovery software available... Read [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery) and search Google and Ask Ubuntu. No guarantees.

Comment: Nope, nothing. How could i be so stupid so as to not have a backup! Overconfidence