# Replaced Window7(4drives) with Ubuntu13.04(empty) Lost all data, TestDisk did not help

Tags: installation, 13.04, partitioning, hard-drive, data-recovery

I have 500gb of HDD with 4 drives on Windows7, While installing Ubuntu 13.04 I selected Replace Windows (Expected to Replace Windows7 on C drive) But it Removed all the Data from other 3 drives and Not its single Empty Ext4 HDD. I have lost All data.

BY referring AskUbuntu Tried TestDisk to recover lost partitions but this did not list any NTFS drives.

Is there any way back to get my Data, I am all ready to keep Ubuntu or go back to Windows to get my data.

I connected this HDD to another Window7 system, it did not recognize this HDD.

Comment: Time to restore from backup.  Don't keep backups?  Hard lesson.

Answer (score 0):

As a lot of people, you deleted all the NTFS partitions with this options. See all this answers to people that asked here as you:

[Did replacing Windows with Ubuntu completely remove Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/232703/did-replacing-windows-with-ubuntu-completely-remove-windows)

[Replaced Windows 7, but where did my old files go?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253936/replaced-windows-7-but-where-did-my-old-files-go)

[How can I recover my data after replacing Windows with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/245987/how-can-i-recover-my-data-after-replacing-windows-with-ubuntu)

[How do I recover my accidentally lost Windows partitions after installing Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu)

I only did this search in Ask Ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/search?q=windows+7+replace

Hope you recover your files.

Comment: thank you for your update, I have went by these link before posting this question. I followed them and Used TestDisk but did not help.